# Log into Facebook via JSoup

Tags: java, facebook, jsoup

So, I have seen other questions on here with few answers or unanswered questions.

I am attempting to log into Facebook to view a profile page that returns a 404 error unless I am logged in.

I believe the issue is that there is extra data or cookies not getting sent to the server along with the web request.

Here is what I currently have.

```
Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1")
                            .data("email", "fake@gmail.com", "pass", "myPassword")
                            .method(Method.POST)
                            .execute();
Document doc = res.parse();
System.out.println(res.cookies());
System.out.println(res.statusMessage());
Document facebookDoc = Jsoup.connect(url).cookies(res.cookies()).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0").referrer("http://www.google.com").get();
```

I have tried with and without the user agent/referrer code.

The last line that attempts to connect to "url" results in a 404 error as if I'm not logged in.  My goal is to get the html of the profile page located at "url".

I tried to take any cookies received during the first POST but it doesn't seem to be accepting it.

What else do I need to do?  If there is another API other than Jsoup that can do this much better then I'm willing to switch.  I noticed some recommending HTMLUnit although I couldn't get it to work.

If the official Facebook API can log me in to view profiles then a reference to that would be great.  It looked like it was for posting to people's timelines and such.

**EDIT**: I solved my login issue by finding someone who suggested using a GET request to the login server before attempting the POST.

```
Response reachPageInitially = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1")
                            .method(Method.GET)
                            .execute();
Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1")
                            .data("email", "myEmail@gmail.com", "pass", "myPassword")
                            .method(Method.POST)
                            .cookies(reachPageInitially.cookies())
                            .execute();
Document doc = res.parse();
System.out.println(res.cookies());
System.out.println(res.statusMessage());
Document facebookDoc = Jsoup.connect(url).cookies(res.cookies()).cookies(reachPageInitially.cookies()).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0").referrer("http://www.google.com").get();
```

Although I've stopped using JSoup and am looking at other solutions as the profile page I'm interested in parsing is pretty much all Javascript and JSoup cannot load JS.

Comment: You might want to add your solution as an answer to this question as well.